# Problem with a delete statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

```
public static void DeleteThreads(int threadID)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("DELETE FROM dbo.Threads");
    sb.Append(" WHERE ThreadsID=@ThreadsID");

    string myConnectionString = AllQuestionsPresented.connectionString;

    using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString))
    {
        myConnection.Open();
        SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sb.ToString(), myConnection);
        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@ThreadsID", SqlDbType.Int);
        sqlCommand.Parameters["@ThreadsID"].Value = threadID;
        sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }
}
```

It gives me this Error:

```
The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_Comments_Threads". The conflict occurred in database "model", table "dbo.Comments", column 'ThreadsID'.
```

The statement has been terminated.

Should this fix that error:

```
enter code here  public static void DeleteComments(int threadID)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("DELETE FROM dbo.Comments");
    sb.Append(" WHERE ThreadsID=@ThreadsID");

    string myConnectionString = AllQuestionsPresented.connectionString;

    using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString))
    {
        myConnection.Open();
        SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sb.ToString(), myConnection);
        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@ThreadsID", SqlDbType.Int);
        sqlCommand.Parameters["@ThreadsID"].Value = threadID;
        sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }
}
```

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: aren't you missing a space between "dbo.Threads" and "WHERE"?

Comment: You seem to be updating your question to be asking something else here. This is very confusing and should be avoided. Firstly several of the comments and indeed answers now seem to be irrelevant unless you read the edit history and more importantly its a new question so should be treated as such. And to explain why its a new question you have changed both the code that is being run and the error message that is being returned. Your error is now in a different place because peopel ahve helped you solve your frist problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have a space, and it looks like you're missing the `FROM` keyword.

Try:

```
sb.Append("DELETE FROM dbo.Threads");    
sb.Append(" WHERE ThreadsID=@ThreadsID");
```

Also, for the record: Using inline SQL is generally bad due to tightly coupling your application to your database. You should use a separate data access layer if this application is for any serious purpose.

Comment: FROM is not needed  but space between keywords and identifiers is.

Comment: @ypercube - Fair enough. I've always used "FROM," so I must have convinced myself that it wasn't optional at some point.

Comment: @Dmitry You have a constraint issue that's preventing you from deleting the row. You can't delete that row until you delete any associated rows from the `Comments` table.

Comment: hmm.. do i need to delete all the comments associated with that thread id... so i need another sql statement says to delete all comments with that ThreadID. Should i execute one statement on the comments and then that statement on the threadID? or how else could i do that?

Comment: @DBM: You have a point though. FROM is not needed in SQL-Server. I'm not at all sure if this valid SQL or an SQl-Server "feature". I've always written `DELETE FROM` too.

Comment: @Dmitry There are a lot of options (you could alter your database schema and remove the constraint, for example). But yes, deleting the associated rows from the Comments table before you delete from your Threads table should work.

Comment: @Dmitry: That could well be a new question for you to post on SO. It depends on how you have created tables (and their FOREIGN KEY constraints)

Comment: Thats what i did.. I run the fucntion to delete all the comments that have that particular id..And then i deleted the thread table associated with that threadID..It worked!!

Answer (score 2):

Include "From" and Space

```
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("DELETE from  dbo.Threads ");
        sb.Append("WHERE ThreadsID=@ThreadsID");
```

Answer (score 2):

You forget to give space after first statement and forget to add FROM thats it.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("DELETE FROM  dbo.Threads  ");
sb.Append(" WHERE ThreadsID=@ThreadsID");
```

Comment: you missed `FROM` keyword either.

Comment: hey already included 2 min back , now i have highlited in answer also

Comment: @LordCover  - form is not necessary you can check this link for referance http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189835.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Just build the string yourself to see what's wrong. The result would be

```
DELETE dbo.ThreadsWHERE ThreadsID=@ThreadsID
```

You're missing the `FROM` keyword and a space after dbo.Threads.

```
sb.Append("DELETE FROM dbo.Threads ");    
sb.Append("WHERE ThreadsID=@ThreadsID");
```

Answer (score 0):

Should it be

```
DELETE FROM ......
```

Answer (score 0):

ThreadsID passed as forign key on comments and other tables, you have to delete that records first associated with that ThreadID. You can set cascade delete option on the master table from SQL Server Management Stidio.